# Calculated Column Requirements

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

KPI (Time) will be triggered from the 6 Milestone Expected Date fields (M1 Date Expected -> M6 Date Expected):

- If the date required of any of the milestone Expected Date field does is not greater exceed today's date and the complete box is not checked then Project KPI field will = Green
- If the date required of any of the milestone Expected Date field is greater than today's date (by less than a week) and the complete box is not checked then Project KPI field will = Amber
- If the date required of any of the milestone Expected Date field is greater than today's date (by more than a week) and the complete box is not checked then Project KPI field will  = Red

Each of our 6 milestones have a date expected and completed (as per the new fields required above). The overall KPI will look across all the milestone date expected fields and generate the KPI status based on any overdue and by how long.

Comment: It might be a good idea to format your text into something which is actually readable. Use Linebreaks and indent code with tabs/4spaces

Comment: Calculated fields can't use [Today], so I don't think there's any way for you to compare a date based on the current date/time. You could create a view for each status/color. Or you could probably create a DataView in Designer with colored rows.

Comment: You could also use a calculated field to run javascript to check the dates in the list view. Check out the third answer on this question... http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/113098/calculated-column-today-work-around

Comment: No Erin, that TODAY trick of adding and deleting a TODAY Column was already debunked in 2008; search for TODAY Formula here on the site.. plenty written about it